# Best approach the load differentiated prices for products per customer?

Tags: magento2, product, price

I would like to have suggestions what a good approach might be for below scenario.

Our client has:

- an external system with product prices in it
- the catalog has ~ 50k products
- product prices differ from client to client
- there is almost no overlap in prices (so each product price is unique for each customer)
- prices are managed in the external system
- prices can change daily
- customers are managed from the external system (and are allready synced with Magento 2)
- the products are already present in Magento 2

What is the best way to load prices in to Magento? Normally I would say a cronjob which syncs prices into the system. But the problem is Magento doesn't support different product prices for each customer.

**What would be a good way to solve this issue in terms of design/architecture.**

Answer (score 0):

I've used this extension a number of times now

https://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-prices-per-customer.html

In terms of import you will have to write your own process. I recommend the process is triggered by using a seperate console script rather than writing something triggered by the magento cron scheduler.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the main question then is can it handle large amounts of data? Lets say 50k products and 1000 customers. Can it handle 50M records?